# How to create a MediaPlayer array based on user input?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, user-input

I am starting android programming and i hit a pickle.

I am trying to do an app that will play a certain sound when pressing a button, stores a value inside textbox and in an array. 
Based on that i would like, by pressing the **button "*trei*"** to play all the sound in the order pressed by the user consecutively.

I tried using for, but it plays all the sounds at the same time. I tried to search for an array of raw files implementation or onCompletition listeners but i don't really understand how to implement them in my case.
**Any kind of help is highly regarded !**
This is the code:

```
public class VocalHelper extends Activity {
int contor,n=1,g,index=0;
int vector[]= new int[22];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vocal_helper);
   final Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button two = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button trei =(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);

    final TextView textView= (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.record_0006);
    final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.record_0005);


    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(contor<20)

            {   vector[n]=1;
                n++;
                String text = " Mi-e foame ";


            textView.append(text);
                textView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(VocalHelper.this, R.anim.abc_fade_in));

           mp.start();
            one.setClickable(false);
            two.setEnabled(false);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        VocalHelper.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               one.setClickable(true);
                                two.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).start();


            contor ++;}
             else
            {   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Numarul maxum de caractere a fost depasit ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}



          /*  Intent intent = new Intent(VocalHelper.this, Sentimente.class);
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);*/

        }
    });

    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(contor<20)
        {   vector[n]=2;
            n++;
            String text = " Da ";

            textView.append(text);
            textView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(VocalHelper.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
            contor ++;
            mp1.start();
            two.setClickable(false);
            one.setEnabled(false);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    VocalHelper.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            two.setClickable(true);
                            one.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();

        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(VocalHelper.this,Alerta_depasire_cuv.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Numarul maxim de caractere a fost depasit ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

           /* Intent intent = new Intent(VocalHelper.this, Sentimente.class);
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);*/

    }
});




    trei.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
           g=n;


         while (g>1) {
               if (vector[g] == 1)
               {  mp.start();
                               }


                   //Toast.makeText(VocalHelper.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               if (vector[g] == 2)
               {      mp1.start();

                           }



            g=g-1;
               //  Toast.makeText(VocalHelper.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

           }
        }
    });
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    contor=0;
    n=0;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_vocal_helper, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```